# Can't get Hive SerDe to work - returns 0 records

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-serde

This is my second attempt of using SerDe. First one worked quiet well but now, I'm really struggling.

I got an XML of this structure:
 [image: XML structure]

This is the Hive table I created

```
CREATE TABLE  raw_abc.text_abc
  (
   publicationid string,
   parentid string,
   id string,
   level string,
   usertypeid string,
   name string,
   assetcrossreferences_ordered string,
   assetcrossreferences MAP<string, string>,
   attributenames_ordered string,
   attributenames map<string,string>,
   seo_ordered  string, 
   seo MAP<string, string>
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.publicationid"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/@PublicationID",
"column.xpath.parentid"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/@ParentID",
"column.xpath.id"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/@ID",
"column.xpath.level"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/@Level",
"column.xpath.usertypeid"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/@UserTypeID",
"column.xpath.name"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/@Name",
"column.xpath.assetcrossreferences_ordered"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/AssetCrossReferences/@Ordered",
"column.xpath.assetcrossreferences"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/AssetCrossReferences/AssetCrossReference",
"column.xpath.attributenames_ordered"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/AttributeNames/@Ordered",
"column.xpath.attributenames"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/AttributeNames/@Ordered",
"column.xpath.seo_ordered"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/SEO/@Ordered",
"column.xpath.seo"="/ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage/Product/SEO"

)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location 's3a://ec-abc-dev/inbound/abc/abc/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage>",
"xmlinput.end"="</ST:ECC-HierarchyMessage>"
)
;
```

Table is created successfully, however, 
when I try select * from raw_abc.text_abc , I get no records in return.
Any idea what's wrong here? I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure it out with no luck.

Thanks,
G

Comment: Have you tried to repair a table if not then try out MSCK REPAIR TABLE raw_abc.text_abc to synchronize the table with the Hive metastore.

Comment: Hi @ShambhuNath yes I did. No luck